# What's wrong about my vs code when the error is "No module named 'pytz'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using vs code to create a piece of texting python code.However,there is an error which read like this:

```
{

    "resource": "/c:/Users/刘啸宇/OneDrive/新建文件夹/python/time.py",

    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",

    "code": "unresolved-import",

    "severity": 4,

    "message": "unresolved import 'pytz'",

    "source": "Python",

    "startLineNumber": 3,

    "startColumn": 8,

    "endLineNumber": 3,

    "endColumn": 12

}
```

Even after I install the "pytz" package,the problem still resists.And when I try to run this code,the terminal print lines like this:

```
     PS C:\Users\刘啸宇\OneDrive\新建文件夹\python> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python37_64/python.exe" c:/Users/刘啸宇/OneDrive/新建文件夹/python/time.py

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:/Users/刘啸宇/OneDrive/新建文件夹/python/time.py", line 3, in <module>
        import pytz as p

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
```

In my computer,I installed vs code with "python" plug-in ,"python extension pack" plug-in and "magicpython" plug-in.Then,I installed visual studio 2019 preview version,which includes python module.Finally,I installed the python3.7(32-bit)(while my computer is 64-bit).And after I encountered this error,I used "pip install pytz" order.But it doesn't seem to work.And in case my PATH settings are wrong,here they are：

```
    C:\Users\刘啸宇\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;

    C:\Users\刘啸宇\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;

    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

    C:\Users\刘啸宇\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;

    C:\mingw64\bin;
```

The first three lines of my code :

```py
import time as t
import datetime as d
import pytz as p
```

Well,the expected result is,after I installed the pytz package,this program should have run successfully.

Comment: If the error is coming only in linter and not when you actually compile the code, that can be because your linter is targeting some different python Installation

Comment: Thank you!Somehow,when I opened the vs code the second day,this code could be compiled and ran.But as you said,there is still an error only in linter. Could you please tell me how to retarget the linter to the right python installation?I'd appreciate it if you could give me a hand.

Comment: Look on the Bottom left, you should be seeing a `Python (3.6)` or something similar, click on it and you should be able to change it from there, if you are unable to find it let me know and I will add an answer with Images.